# VW / Grid strange behavior

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a problem with `vw`that I can't explain, in the`footer`I created a`div`with`width: 50 vw`and when I go to view the result on the site I see that it doesn't reach exactly halfway. It could be also a problem with the`grid display`, but when i use the google developer tool the first `div width`is the same to the second and also the`div`in the`footer`has the same`width`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="stile1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <div><img src="IMG\La_Mita.png" alt="Logo"></div>
  <span></span>
  <span class="simbol"><div><img src="IMG\casa.png" alt="smbl"></div><div>Home</div></span> 
  <span></span>
  <span class="simbol"><div><img src="IMG\pettine.png" alt="smbl"></div><div>Storia</div></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="simbol"><div><img src="IMG\shampoo.png" alt="smbl"></div><div>Prodotti</div></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="simbol"><div><img src="IMG\One.png" alt="smbl"></div><div>Capelli</div></span>
  <span></span>
  <div><img src="IMG\La_Mita.png" alt="Logo"></div>
 </header>

 <div class="immagine1"><img class="salon" src="IMG\Salone_1.jpg" alt="salone"></div>
 
 <main>
  <div class="div1"><img src="IMG\phone.jpg" alt="salone"></div>
  <div class="div2">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.c</div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.<img src="IMG\phone.jpg" alt="salone"></div>
  <div class="div1"><img src="IMG\phone.jpg" alt="salone"></div>
  <div class="div2">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut neque, eius, perspiciatis fugit rerum magnam vel illo repellat provident a porro totam doloribus voluptates nihil quas facilis commodi? Reiciendis, ducimus.</div>
 </main>

 <footer>
  <div>
   dvg
  </div>
  <div>
   hh
  </div>
 </footer>

 
</body>

</html>
```

```
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 margin: 0%;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;
}

div:has(img){
 line-height: 0%;
}

img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}


header {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #F5B01B;
 position: sticky;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 top: 0px;
 height: 8vh;
 z-index: 1;
}

header div {
 width: calc(110px + 3%);
 object-fit: cover;
}

.simbol {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

 img[alt="smbl"]{
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  object-fit: cover;
 }

img[alt="Logo"]{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}

.immagine1{
 background-color: #75540D;
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100%;
}

.salon{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

main {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-auto-rows: calc(50vw);
}

.div1{
 grid-column: 1/4;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F7C865;
} 

.div2{
 grid-column: 4/7;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F7C865;
} 


footer {
 background-color: chocolate;
 height: 10vh;
}

footer > div {
 background-color: aquamarine;
 width: 50vw;
}
```

[first `grid` div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDn5v.jpg)
[second `grid` div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWAIb.jpg)
[div in the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGHqp.png)

i try to change `vw` in `%` and it work, but i want learn way with this metod the code doesn't work.
thanks

Comment: a `div` cannot be a child element of a `span`. A div as a block-level element cannot be placed within an inline element

Comment: add images to your code so we can see the full layout and the actual problem